# Excluding certain sp3-hybridized carbons with SMARTS

Tags: rdkit, smiles

[image]

Let's say I have a compound shown above (SMILES: `CCC(F)(F)F`), and I want to exclude the trifluoromethyl group with SMARTS, how would I do that? I have tried `[CX4;!$(C(F)(F)F)]` but it does not exclude `C(F)(F)F` according to RDKit:

```
molecule = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CCC(F)(F)F')
pattern = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[CX4;!$(C(F)(F)F)]')
molecule.HasSubstructMatch(pattern) --> expected False, but returns True
```

I think the recursive portion is written incorrectly but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Comment: In your code, the SMARTS reads `[CX4;!$(C(F)(F)F)]` with `;` not `&` I don't have time to investigate, but SMARTS viewer is usually helpful for these: https://smarts.plus

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Ah sorry, I corrected it to avoid confusion. I actually tried several variations of the SMARTS patterns and none of them worked. Based on the SMARTS viewer `[CX4;!$(C(F)(F)F)]` looks correct, but clearly I'm missing something

Comment: I believe a duplicate here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150737/what-is-an-appropriate-way-to-write-a-recursive-smarts-that-excludes-trifluorome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SMARTS works.

To see what a SMARTS finds, it is always a good idea to depict the result.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole

patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[CX4;!$(C(F)(F)F)]')

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CCC(F)(F)F')

m.GetSubstructMatches(patt)
m
```

[image: notrifluor]

The SMARTS should find all Carbons with 4 connections (implicit Hydrogen count), but not (C(F)(F)F).
That is why `HasSubstructMatch` returns True.